# Sklearn Precision and recall giving wrong values

Tags: python, scikit-learn, decision-tree, precision-recall

[image]

Why is my precision score so low in the above image?

Comment: Please don't upload images of your errors: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see in your comments that you're trying to interpret confusion_matrix as `[[tp, fp], [fn, tn]]`

Based on [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.confusion_matrix.html), `sklearn.confusion_matrix` is a function that returns an array of:

`[[tn, fp], [fn, tp]]`

So, it's vice-versa and the calculation is right:

```
397 / (397 + 925) = 0.30030257...
```